# java.lang.LinkageError: com.facebook.litho.sections.widget.RecyclerCollectionComponent

Tags: linkageerror, litho, facebook-litho

```
java.lang.LinkageError: com.facebook.litho.sections.widget.RecyclerCollectionComponent
```

When using litho RecyclerCollectionComponent

```
RecyclerCollectionComponent component = RecyclerCollectionComponent.create(c).section(
                    section
            ).setRootAsync(false).disablePTR(true).build();
```

Comment: Could you please post the full error?

Comment: It's the full error, shows error and restarts the screen

Answer (score 0):

After wasting a couple of days I found out this is due to a bug in litho framework,
I solved it by using an older version of Litho.

try using

```
implementation 'com.facebook.litho:litho-core:0.12.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.litho:litho-widget:0.12.0'
compileOnly 'com.facebook.litho:litho-annotations:0.12.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.facebook.litho:litho-processor:0.12.0'
// Sections
implementation 'com.facebook.litho:litho-sections-core:0.12.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.litho:litho-sections-widget:0.12.0'
compileOnly 'com.facebook.litho:litho-sections-annotations:0.12.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.facebook.litho:litho-sections-processor:0.12.0'
// SoLoader
implementation 'com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.2.0'
```